# I have one table in my DB, one column of which has XML in it. How can I fetch the value of a tag of a XML? please suggest SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

In the below sample XML I want to find value of 'TAG2' which is 'TO BE FOUND' ----->
Please suggest the select statement for the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<reply timestamp='07:49:51:763'>
<dataApp processor='abcd.com' stencilId='INDIA' indText='0' class='RULES'>
<status code='000' severity='I' msg='Service Execution successful' classifier='I:kernel'/>
<var id='QWERTY1' v='' f='X' attrsASF='000000100000110000000001'/>
<var id='QWERTY2' v='20200302' f='D' attrsASF='000000000000000000000000'/>
<var id='QWERTY3' v='20991231' f='D' attrsASF='000000000000000000000000'/>
<var id='QWERTY4' v='*' f='X' attrsASF='000000100000110000000001'/>
<var id='QWERTY5' v='0' f='N' attrsASF='000000100000110000000000'/>
<var id='QWERTY6' v='1' f='N' attrsASF='000000100000110000000000'/>
000000000000'/>
<var id='OS_USERUID' v='ABCD' f='X' attrsASF='000000100000110000000001'/>
<tfo n='IGS'>
    <attr n='TAG1' v='AAAA' f='X' m='I'/>
    <attr n='TAG2' v='TO BE FOUND' f='D' m='I'/>
```

Comment: You are trying to get the value of an attribute. This can be done using XMLQUERY inside a SELECT. If you have trouble writing that query, post the query as part of your question.

Comment: Try [XMLTABLE table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022195.html)

Comment: @data_henrik could you please help me with the select statement.

Comment: Add the query you tried and the error or problem

Comment: @data_henrik,Thanks for the reply

I am really not sure about the syntax for this query
I tried copying somewhere from google 
SELECT XMLQUERY FROM (doc("TableName.xmlcolumn.xml")/tfo/attr[2]) 
Error Message: An unexpected token "doc" was found following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. You may uncommend the commented out block to run the statement as is.

```
/*
WITH MYTAB (XML) AS
(
VALUES XMLPARSE 
(
DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<reply timestamp="07:49:51:763">
  <dataApp processor="abcd.com" stencilId="INDIA" indText="0" class="RULES">
    <tfo n="IGS">
      <attr n="TAG1" v="AAAA" f="X" m="I"/>
      <attr n="TAG2" v="TO BE FOUND" f="D" m="I"/>
    </tfo>   
  </dataApp>
</reply>
'
)
)
*/
SELECT X.V
FROM 
  MYTAB T
, XMLTABLE
(
'$doc/reply/dataApp/tfo/attr[@n="TAG2"]' PASSING T.XML AS "doc"
COLUMNS 
  V VARCHAR(20) PATH '@v'
) X;
```

[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=211d4cb7694d5eb6bf1cee9a513ecb59)

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thank you for your kind reply.
I tried the query provided by you and got the error below:

DB2 SQL-Error: -109
SQLState: 42601

Could you please suggest where I need to correct .

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: Db2 V11.1 fixpack 2
Installed on Windows 2016 servers

Comment: @DheerajNagrani I've added a dbfiddle link with the same example. It must work on any Db2 for LUW database. Have you tried the example **as is**? If you get such an error on your own statement, then, please, provide a fully reproducible example of data and your statement.

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thank you so much for the help, yes this query worked for me. :)